# how to check for not null column constraint in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

How do i check if a column in a table has a not null constraint in an oracle db? Can it be checked with the data dictionary?

Comment: This question was asked before, take a look:
[stackoverflow nullable column][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028956/modify-column-in-oracle-how-to-check-if-a-column-is-nullable-before-setting-to

Answer (score 19):

```
SELECT nullable
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE owner = <<owner of table>>
   AND table_name = <<name of table>>
   AND column_name = <<name of column>>
```

will work assuming the column is marked NOT NULL rather than, say, having a `CHECK` constraint that checks that it is non-NULL.

Comment: People who use check constraints rather than column DDL to define not null columo.ns should be severely spoken to.

Comment: @APC, agreed, but internally Oracle represents those `NOT NULL` columns with check constraints. They're utterly indistinguishable from `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`. RRgghgh. >:-(