# Modify a column to NULL - Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table named `CUSTOMER`, with few columns. One of them is `Customer_ID`.

Initially `Customer_ID` column `WILL NOT` accept `NULL` values.

I've made some changes from code level, so that `Customer_ID` column will accept `NULL` values by default.

Now my requirement is that, I need to again make this column to accept `NULL` values.

For this I've added executing the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer MODIFY Customer_ID nvarchar2(20) NULL
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-01451 error, the column already allows null entries so
therefore cannot be modified
```

This is because already I've made the `Customer_ID` column to accept `NULL` values.

Is there a way to check if the column will accept `NULL` values before executing the above query...??

Comment: You can find the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028956/modify-column-in-oracle-how-to-check-if-a-column-is-nullable-before-setting-to

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the column NULLABLE in [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277). This tells you whether the column allows nulls using a binary Y/N flag.

If you wanted to put this in a script you could do something like:

```
declare

   l_null user_tab_columns.nullable%type;

begin

   select nullable into l_null
     from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'CUSTOMER'
      and column_name = 'CUSTOMER_ID';

   if l_null = 'N' then
      execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE Customer 
                          MODIFY (Customer_ID nvarchar2(20) NULL)';
   end if;

end;
```

It's best *not* to use dynamic SQL in order to alter tables. Do it manually and be sure to double check everything first.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can just ignore the error:

```
declare
    already_null exception;
    pragma exception_init (already_null , -01451);
begin
    execute immediate 'alter table <TABLE> modify(<COLUMN> null)';
    exception when already_null then null;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You might encounter this error when you have previously provided a `DEFAULT ON NULL` value for the `NOT NULL` column.

If this is the case, to make the column nullable, you must also reset its default value to `NULL` when you modify its nullability constraint.

eg:

```sql
DEFINE table_name = your_table_name_here
DEFINE column_name = your_column_name_here;

ALTER TABLE &table_name
  MODIFY (
    &column_name
      DEFAULT NULL
      NULL
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this, it worked fine.
Try to execute query, if any error occurs, catch `SQLException`.

```
try {
stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE Customer MODIFY Customer_ID nvarchar2(20) NULL");
} catch (SQLException sqe) {
Logger("Column to be modified to NULL is already NULL : " + sqe);
}
```

Is this correct way of doing?

Answer (score 0):

To modify the constraints of an existing table

for example... add `not null` constraint to a column.

Then follow the given steps:

1) Select the table in which you want to modify changes.

2) Click on `Actions..` ---> select column ----> add.

3) Now give the column name, datatype, size, etc. and click ok.

4) You will see that the column is added to the table.

5) Now click on `Edit` button lying on the left side of `Actions` button.

6) Then you will get various table modifying options.

7) Select the `column` from the list.

8) Select the particular column in  which you want to give `not null`.

9) Select `Cannot be null` from `column properties`.

10) That's it.