# Is it possible to get metadata on a nested table/array from Java code?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, nested-table

Normally for a user defined type I can simply do the following (Simplified but functional example):

```
//Create table
create type myType1 as object( a char(2), b char(2) );
create type myTable1 as table of myType1;

//Java code
ArrayDescriptor  des  = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "MYTABLE1", con);
StructDescriptor sDes = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor( des.getBaseName(), con);

//Populte the metadata
String  columnName = sDes.getColumnName(0);
int     oracleType = sDes.getColumnType(0);
int     maxSize    = sDes.getColumnDisplaySize(0);
boolean isNullable = sDes.isNullable(0)>0;
```

Except now I have a table that's defined with a primitive type instead of a struct, and I can't seem to access the metadata.  My current code is:

```
//Create table
create or replace type myTable2 as table of char(2);

//Java code
ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "MYTABLE2", con);
//This next line would throw an exception, as CHAR type is not a structure
//StructDescriptor sDes = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor( des.getBaseName(), con);

//Populte the metadata    
int     oracleType = descriptor.getBaseType(); // This Works
String  columnName = "COLUMN_VALUE";           // This Works (I think)
int     maxSize    = ????                      // How do I access the '2'?
boolean isNullable = ????                      // How do I access isNullable?
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understand you right. If you can get column info, you can try following codes.

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();

ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null,null, tableName, null);
while(columns.next())
{
    String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    String datatype = columns.getString("DATA_TYPE");
    String columnsize = columns.getString("COLUMN_SIZE");
    String decimaldigits = columns.getString("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
    String isNullable = columns.getString("IS_NULLABLE");
    String is_autoIncrment = columns.getString("IS_AUTOINCREMENT");
}
```

Comment: I cannot get the column info for this table.  The line `ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null,null, tableName, null);` returns an empty `ResultSet`.

Comment: I updated the first example to better highlight the differences.

Comment: @billie i tried it and it works. Are you sure that your connection is truth.

Comment: I tried again using every combination I could think of to get it to work, no luck.  The `ResultSet` is always empty.  I am able to use this method to pull up information about other full tables, it just doesn't work for the array.

Answer (score 0):

At times, in a real-world enterprise environment where you don't have admin perms on an Oracle DB, you might not be able to rely on Java's `DatabaseMetaData` class but you might be able to rely on DDL queries. By that, I mean that you might be able to execute DDL queries as you would normally run a SQL query in your Java app.

For example:

1. You might be able to get the datatype of the column by executing the following query as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377322/4851565): `select t.data_type from user_tab_columns t where t.TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE1' and t.COLUMN_NAME='COLUMN_VALUE'`.
2. You might be able to get the display size of the column by executing the following query as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276344/4851565): `SELECT data_length FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE1' AND column_name = 'COLUMN_VALUE'`.
3. You might be able to get the nullability of the column by executing the following query as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028966/4851565): `select nullable from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'MYTABLE1' and column_name = 'COLUMN_VALUE';`.